# Black bar appears with position: absolute;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble removing this **black bar** at the **top of my loader.**

I went and removed an unneeded div and that created some problems.

Here we have the loader with the black bar, but since the `<div class="text">` was removed I attempted to figure out what was the root cause, and it was `position: absolute;`

```
.doge{ /*This makes the text disappear*/
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}




 .doge{ /*This makes the text appear & Black bars appear at the top of loader*/
    padding: 30px;

 }
```

I added the property to the .doge class and it got rid of the text. **Also is there a way to delay the text so the animation can play?**

``

Original Text: https://jsfiddle.net/Kryometric/fdxsgbga/

Original Loader without black bar at top & strange text: https://jsfiddle.net/chrnysbw/

Loader with black bar & normal text: https://jsfiddle.net/chrnysbw/1/

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired behavior is? Do you want the black bar at the top with the white loader animation? If not, remove the padding on .doge.

Comment: @dogwoodtree-dot-net Wow that worked! I feel really stupid now... xD Is there a way to delay the text so the animation can play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the black bar at the top of the page with the white loader animation, remove the padding on div.doge.

To delay your text arriving on the page, first hide it (like with css display: none;) then use javascript to show it. If you're using jQuery, [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/). Wrap that all in a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) and you're good to go.